# Bootstrap Carousel Next/Prev not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am working with Twitter Bootstrap Carousel and though I am not very familiar with .js, somehow I got things working fine.

The only problem is that the next/prev button is working in a strange way.

Here's my temp site:
http://tokyo-flaneur.com/dl/donner/contents/menu.html

Although I have 10 images, I can not get to the No.10 by clicking the next button. After the third image, when I click on the next button, the image goes back to No.2.

Also, whichever image I am looking, when I click the prev button, it goes all the way back to No.1.

Could anyone help me or direct me to the right direction? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You handle slider's next/prev buttons with your own handler, so it slide to 2nd element 1st, than tries to make `next()`

replace:

```
$("#myCarousel a").click(function(e){ 
    var index = $(this).index(); 
    //when hitting NEXT button index always 2, for PREV - 0
    slider.carousel(index); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

with

```
$("#myCarousel .slider-pager a").click(function(e){ 
    var index = $(this).index(); 
    slider.carousel(index); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

in your onpage  script

Comment: Thank you, eicto!!! Thank you so much!!
I wouldn't have been able to fix this myself.

Comment: What is "slider" in this context?

Comment: @dpk I don't remember well, most probably it is jquery object `#myCarousel`

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors to this question:

Use attribute `data-interval="false"` (Bootstrap 3.3.5):

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
```

Here are other supported carousel options in Bootstrap 3:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage

---

Earlier versions:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yv80533m/)</kbd>

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <h4>A mind-bending lecture on applied philosophy by Oxford lecturer Ravi Zacharias.</h4>
            <br>
            <span class="font-normal">youtube/watch?v=3ZZaoavCsYE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>Director of the Human Genome Project discusses the greatest mystery of life</h4>
            <br>
            <span class="font-normal">youtube/watch?v=EGu_VtbpWhE</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="" class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div><!-- #myCarousel -->

<script>
    $(function(){

        $('.carousel-control').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#myCarousel').carousel( $(this).data() );
        });

    });//END document.ready
</script>
```

---

*Note: this answer requires jQuery, so ensure that library is loaded. Of course, bootstrap requires jQuery so you should already have it referenced.*